# Unable to upload 200mb PDF file in Java

Tags: java

I am able to upload PDF files which has 7MB of data but i'm not able to upload more than 7MB. Can anyone provide example of how to upload a 200MB file using SMB protocol while using Angular code to handle the 200MB PDF file

**Service Code:**

```
SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(efbiFile);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 200];
BufferedOutputStream bufos = new BufferedOutputStream(sfos,buf.length);
final ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = 
Channels.newChannel(fileObj.getInputStream());
final WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(bufos);                             
ChannelTools.fastChannelCopy(inputChannel,outputChannel);
inputChannel.close();
outputChannel.close();
```

Comment: what error code do you get?

Comment: It's not returning any status code and executing this code observer.error(xhr.response) and not able to upload a file

Answer (score 2):

You most likely don't want to allocate a 200 MB buffer (`new byte[1024 * 1024 * 200]`). The purpose of the `BufferedOutputStream` is to improve the overall performance of many small writes, and not to store the entire input in the RAM.

You can use [`InputStream.transferTo(OutputStream )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)) method and start with default `BufferedOutputStream` size of 8196:

```
try (InputStream in = fileObj.getInputStream();
     SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(efbiFile);
     BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(sfos)) {
  in.transferTo(out);
  out.flush(); // In case SmbFileOutputStream doesn't implement this correctly
}
```

Comment: What Java version are you on? This method was added in Java 9.

Comment: I'm using Java 8